# Cloud foundry across multiple locations

Tags: location, cloud-foundry

If I have two servers. One in the USA and one in Europe.
How would I use Cloudfoundry on those?

Do I simply deploy a single Cloud Foundry Instance on those two servers?
Am I able to push an app to a specific server? (say I want two instances in Europe and one in the US)
And will CF then redirect requests from different locations to the nearest server?

If I was to set up two different CF Instances, (One in the US and one in Europe), would they be able to cooperate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible, you can search for "Cloud Foundry multiple datacenters" or other such terms to see how different users have implemented this.  One good starting resource is [this presentation](http://www.altoros.com/cflive/multi-data-center-as-a-cloud-foundry-deployment-pattern/). There are all sorts of trade-offs to be made when doing such a setup, so there is not just a single solution.  Also, [this proposal](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1BZL4GwluaRtUVfeW-j8_ezBJQmwnhGqcMNvQIy9ltZE/edit#heading=h.j5uq3a7vh7d0) will bring one particular solution into the core of OSS CF.